# VirtualBox shows optical drives that are already removed

Tags: virtualbox

After starting a VM and going to the menu "Devices" -> "Optical Drives" I still see the drives that I previously removed in "Global Tools" -> Tab "Optical disks".

How to get rid of them? They remain even after reinstallation of VirtualBox. Their paths aren't valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it finally.

After I removed the path to the image

```
/tmp/backup/kubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
```

in the following files

```
./.config/VirtualBoxrc
./.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml
./.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml-prev
```

in the HOME directory the image also disappeared from the UI.